# Full throttle oscillations

Tags: betaflight, multirotor

When I give full throttle with a full 4s battery I get vibrations.

After a while of flying the vibrations disappear.

Everything is fixed (no loose parts)
Filters are on 1x multipler.
RPM filters are enabled.

- 2207 2750kv iFlight Xing motors
- TBS Source One frame
- JohnyFPV Props

This is not a new build. I am flying this quad since 1/2 a year now. RPM filters were on 2x originally.

Comment: What Sensor & PID Loop Frequency do you use and on what Processor? Have you checked that the Processor can process the loops reliably? Because RPM-Filtering needs significantly more CPU Resources than standard filtering

Comment: It's a F7 and the PID-Loop is fine (checked in CLI)

Comment: I recommend trying a few different types of props as that will likely solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I did increase tpa about 10%. This did fix my problem!

tpa will lower pid-values at higher throttle.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of could be causing this.

The first is that, whilst your frame bolts are secure, your prop nuts could be loose, so the sudden acceleration of the motor causes slippage.

The second is that your props are flattening under the high RPM. I have only experienced this once but switching to a different set of props solved the issue.

Comment: Hi :) ... an no! Motor screws are tight and i am using the johnyFPV Props since 1/2 year on exact this motors.

Comment: @heavykick hi :) when you say motor screws, do you mean the screws holding your motors to your frame, or the nuts holding on your props? And sometimes, you just get slightly weaker props. When I experienced it, I was using some clear Avan props which had terrible oscillations. I switched to another set of Avans and it flies awesome! If you have a spare set, it might be worth putting them on just to see.

Comment: fresh props. And I do mean all screws and nuts are tight...

Comment: @heavykick that’s odd - I’m interested to see the other answers to see what I’ve missed

Comment: I will go on the field now with this drone and try to increase tpa ... we will see!